# Retrieve a value between XML node positions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am trying to retrieve values from preceding elements. But the value I try to retrieve needs to be after a certain position and before an other nodes position. How can I do this?

**Example XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>503</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>co</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>cou</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>87</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>st</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>wta</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>pi</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>64</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>st</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>del</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>27</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>wa</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>dec</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
</actions>
```

**Current XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/actions">
        <result>
            <!-- Loop through all action elements -->
            <xsl:for-each select="action">
                <!-- Display only the needed action in the result file -->
                <xsl:if test="code = 'co' or code = 'st' or code = 'dec' or code = 'pi' or code = 'del'">
                    <action>
                        <code>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="code = 'co'">1</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="code = 'st'">5</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="code = 'dec'">2</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="code = 'pi'">3</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="code = 'del'">4</xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </code>
                        <!-- Get some positions in variables -->
                        <xsl:variable name="previousPosition"><xsl:value-of select="position() - 1" /></xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="lastTRPosition"><xsl:value-of select="count((preceding::action[code = 'tr'])[last()]/preceding::action)+1" /></xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="currentPosition"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:variable>
                        <!-- Should be the value of the preceding action element with code 'tr' (last occurence). But only use when between the last preceding action element with code 'tr' and the current node position NO known code is used ('co', 'st', 'dec', 'pi' or 'del') -->
                        <value>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="(preceding::action[code = 'tr']/value)[last()] != ''"> <!-- some work to do here -->
                                            <xsl:value-of select="round((preceding::action[code = 'tr']/value)[last()])" />
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                        </value>
                    </action>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <action>
        <code>1</code>
        <value>503</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>5</code>
        <value>87</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>3</code>
        <value>87</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>5</code>
        <value>64</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>4</code>
        <value>64</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>2</code>
        <value>27</value>
    </action>
</result>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <action>
        <code>1</code>
        <value>503</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>5</code>
        <value>87</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>3</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>5</code>
        <value>64</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>4</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>2</code>
        <value>27</value>
    </action>
</result>
```

**The changes and why?**

```
<action>
    <code>3</code>
    <value>87</value> <!-- should be 0 -->
</action>
```

This should be 0. Because between the position of the last `action/code = 'tr'` and the current position() of the node to write in the result is a known code 'st' which has already this value.

```
<action>
    <code>4</code>
    <value>64</value>
</action>
```

This should be 0. Because between the position of the last `action/code = 'tr'` and the current position() of the node to write in the result is a known code 'st' which has already this value.

I am a bit stuck in getting the correct test in the `xsl:when`. Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to group with `group-starting-with` and then to use the `>>` operator to filter. I have also made the mapping a parameter and used a key to map efficiently, so altogether I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="code" match="code" use="@from"/>

    <xsl:param name="code-map">
      <code from="co" to="1"/>
      <code from="st" to="5"/>
      <code from="dec" to="2"/>
      <code from="pi" to="3"/>
      <code from="del" to="4"/>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/actions">
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="action" group-starting-with="action[code = 'tr']">
              <xsl:variable name="tr-head" select="."/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::action[code = $code-map/code/@from]]">
                <xsl:with-param name="tr" select="$tr-head"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="action">
      <xsl:param name="tr"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <code>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('code', code, $code-map)/@to"/>
        </code>
        <value>
          <xsl:value-of 
            select="if (not(exists((current-group() except $tr) 
                                    [current() >> . and code = $code-map/code/@from])))
                    then $tr/value else 0"/>
        </value>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I used Saxon 9.5 to transform the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>503</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>co</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>cou</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>87</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>st</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>wta</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>pi</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>64</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>st</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>del</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>tr</code>
        <value>27</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>wa</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
    <action>
        <code>dec</code>
        <value>0</value>
    </action>
</actions>
```

I get the wanted result

```
<result>
   <action>
      <code>1</code>
      <value>503</value>
   </action>
   <action>
      <code>5</code>
      <value>87</value>
   </action>
   <action>
      <code>3</code>
      <value>0</value>
   </action>
   <action>
      <code>5</code>
      <value>64</value>
   </action>
   <action>
      <code>4</code>
      <value>0</value>
   </action>
   <action>
      <code>2</code>
      <value>27</value>
   </action>
</result>
```

Comment: Martin, could you explain the row `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::action[code = $code-map/code/@from]]">`, because I try to insert your solution in the total stylesheet I have, but I can't get it working. Looks like this row does not give any output. See complete source XML and XSLT here: http://pastebin.com/JC9Gqdgb

Comment: Looks like the problem arises because of the default namespace in the document `xmlns="http://www.company.com/log/lk/pl"`. I don't quite understand why

Comment: @MarkVeenstra, as your XSLT defines a default namespace for elements, the elements inside the `param` I set up also end up in that namespace and that way the path `$code-map/code/@from` does not select them. You need to put `<xsl:param name="code-map" xmlns="">...</xsl:param>` on the parameter to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only because i stated it, here a  xslt-1.0 solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="action" />

    <xsl:template match="action [code = 'co' or code = 'st' or code = 'dec' or code = 'pi' or code = 'del']" >
        <result>
            <xsl:copy>
                <code>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="code = 'co'">1</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="code = 'st'">5</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="code = 'dec'">2</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="code = 'pi'">3</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="code = 'del'">4</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </code>
            <value>
                <xsl:variable name="ptr" select="preceding-sibling::action[code='tr'][1]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="trpos" select="count($ptr/preceding-sibling::action)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="pcode" select="preceding-sibling::action[code = 'co' or code = 'st' or code = 'dec' or code = 'pi' or code = 'del'][1]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="codepos" select="count($pcode/preceding-sibling::action)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$trpos >= $codepos">
                        <xsl:value-of select="round($ptr/value)" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </value>
            </xsl:copy>
        </result>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/actions">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="action" />
        </result>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```